# Bucket_selector on nested agg bucket doesn't works

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to make an aggregation on a sibling's children aggregation to filter bucket based on a requested quantity condition, so here is my query :

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
            "terms": {
                    "product.id": [20,21,22,23,24]
                }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "carts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "item.cart_key"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_product": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "quantity": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "item.quantity"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "filtered_product_quantity": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "productId": "unique_product.key",
              "productQuantity": "unique_product>quantity"
            },
            "script": {
              "params": {
                "requiredQuantities": {
                  "20": null,
                  "21": null,
                  "22": null,
                  "23": 3,
                  "24": null
                }
              },
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "params.requiredQuantities[params.productId] <= params.productQuantity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "",
    "phase": "fetch",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
      "reason": "buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [Object[]] at aggregation [unique_product]"
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Here is a sample document set :

```
[

    {
        product.id: 12,
        item.cart_key: abc_123,
        item.quantity: 2
    },
    {
        product.id: 11,
        item.cart_key: abc_123,
        item.quantity: 1
    },
    {
        product.id: 23,
        item.cart_key: def_456,
        item.quantity: 1
    }

]
```

Is it the appropriate aggregation in use ?

In other way, I would like to :

1. Aggregate my documents by cart_key.
2. Per product.id , sum the quantity
3. Filter aggregations that have a quantity higher than a given Record object `{[product.id]: minimum_quantity}` (here is the requiredQuantities param

I don't know if the source script will works as elasticsearch can't reach it.

Comment: Can you paste one sample document ?

Comment: I have updated my topic

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you handle the problem correctly, but here an hacky working solution

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "carts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "item.cart_key"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_product": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "quantity": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "item.quantity"
              }
            },
            "hackProductId": {
              "max": {
                "field": "product.id"
              }
            },
            "filtered_product_quantity": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "productQuantity": "quantity",
                  "productId": "hackProductId"
                },
                "script": {
                  "params": {
                    "requiredQuantities": {
                      "12": 0,
                      "11": 0,
                      "22": 0,
                      "23": 0,
                      "24": 0
                    }
                  },
                  "lang": "painless",
                  "source": "params.requiredQuantities[((int)params.productId).toString()] <= params.productQuantity"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```