# Elasticsearch 7.x error: buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Is the following query with Elasticsearch 7.x even possible?

```json
GET /graylog_*/_search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "hits__pod-b6a3b3e1ab4ddde42361e94107": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "episode_id": [
                      "pod-b6a3b3e1ab4ddde42361e94107"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "downloads": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "status": {
                          "value": "200"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "bytes_sent": {
                          "from": 2097152,
                          "to": null,
                          "include_lower": true,
                          "include_upper": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "medias": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "episode_id",
                "size": 5,
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                "order": [
                  {
                    "_count": "desc"
                  },
                  {
                    "_key": "asc"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "allStreams": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "status": {
                      "value": "206",
                      "boost": 1.0
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "streams": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "time",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "calendar_interval": "day"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "streams": {
                  "multi_terms": {
                    "size": 65536,
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "order": [
                      {
                        "_count": "desc"
                      },
                      {
                        "_key": "asc"
                      }
                    ],
                    "terms": [
                      {
                        "field": "media"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "ip_hash"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "http_user_agent"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "aggregations": {
                                      "transferred": {
                    "sum": {
                      "field": "bytes_sent"
                    }
                  },
                  "threshold": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                      "buckets_path": {
                        "total": "transferred"
                      },
                      "script": {
                        "source": "params.total > 2097152",
                        "lang": "painless"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "valid_streams": {
                "stats_bucket": {
                  "buckets_path": [
                    "streams>transferred"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
        "hits_in_sum": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "sum1": "allStreams>streams>valid_streams.count",
              "sum2": "downloads"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.sum1 + params.sum2",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "track_total_hits": false
}
```

I get this error:

```
    Elastic\Elasticsearch\Exception\ServerResponseException
    500 Internal Server Error: {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"","phase":"fetch","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[],"caused_by":{"type":"aggregation_execution_exception","reason":"buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [Object[]] at aggregation [allStreams]"}},"status":500}
```

The following is the problematic part:

```json
{
  "hits_in_sum": {
    "bucket_script": {
      "buckets_path": {
        "sum1": "allStreams>streams>valid_streams.count",
        "sum2": "downloads"
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "params.sum1 + params.sum2",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the mapping:

```json
{
  "graylog_12": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "internal_fields": {
            "match": "gl2_*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "store_generic": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "body_bytes_sent": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "bytes_sent": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "collection_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "domain": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "episode_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "facility": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "facility_num": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "feed": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "from_nginx": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "full_message": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "city": {
              "properties": {
                "geoname_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "names": {
                  "properties": {
                    "de": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "en": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "es": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ja": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "pt-BR": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ru": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "zh-CN": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "continent": {
              "properties": {
                "code": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "geoname_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "names": {
                  "properties": {
                    "de": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "en": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "es": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ja": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "pt-BR": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ru": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "zh-CN": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "country": {
              "properties": {
                "geoname_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "is_in_european_union": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "iso_code": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "names": {
                  "properties": {
                    "de": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "en": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "es": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ja": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "pt-BR": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ru": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "zh-CN": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "location": {
              "properties": {
                "accuracy_radius": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "latitude": {
                  "type": "float"
                },
                "longitude": {
                  "type": "float"
                },
                "metro_code": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "time_zone": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "postal": {
              "properties": {
                "code": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "registered_country": {
              "properties": {
                "geoname_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "is_in_european_union": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "iso_code": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "names": {
                  "properties": {
                    "de": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "en": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "es": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ja": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "pt-BR": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ru": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "zh-CN": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "represented_country": {
              "properties": {
                "geoname_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "is_in_european_union": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "iso_code": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "names": {
                  "properties": {
                    "de": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "en": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "es": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ja": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "pt-BR": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ru": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "zh-CN": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "type": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "subdivisions": {
              "properties": {
                "geoname_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "iso_code": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "names": {
                  "properties": {
                    "de": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "en": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "es": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ja": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "pt-BR": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "ru": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "zh-CN": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "traits": {
              "properties": {
                "ip_address": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "is_anonymous": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "is_anonymous_proxy": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "is_anonymous_vpn": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "is_hosting_provider": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "is_legitimate_proxy": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "is_public_proxy": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "is_satellite_provider": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "is_tor_exit_node": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "gl2_accounted_message_size": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "gl2_message_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "gl2_processing_error": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "gl2_processing_timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        },
        "gl2_receive_timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        },
        "gl2_remote_ip": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "gl2_remote_port": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "gl2_source_input": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "gl2_source_node": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http_referrer": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http_user_agent": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http_version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http_x_forwarded_for": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ip_hash": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "json": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "level": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "media": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "nginx_access": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "nginx_server_type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "origin": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "remote_addr": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "remote_user": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "request": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "request_body": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "request_method": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "request_scheme": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "request_time": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "source": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "streams": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        },
        "upstream_addr": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "upstream_cache_status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent_details": {
          "properties": {
            "bot": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "brandname": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "category": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "client": {
              "properties": {
                "engine": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "engine_version": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "family": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "short_name": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "type": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "version": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "device": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "devicetype": {
              "properties": {
                "browser": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "camera": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "carbrowser": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "console": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "desktop": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "featurephone": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "feedreader": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "mediaplayer": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "mobile": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "mobileapp": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "peripheral": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "phablet": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "pim": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "portablemediaplay": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "smartdisplay": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "smartphone": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "smartspeaker": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "tablet": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "touchenabled": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "tv": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "wearable": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              }
            },
            "model": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "os": {
              "properties": {
                "family": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "platform": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "short_name": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "version": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "producer": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "url": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "url": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "useragent": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I really do not know why this would not work or how I could get it to work. I have gone through every article here on SF, asked CHatGPT, checked the Elastic forums. I guess I am just missing something obvious as an Elastic newbie. Any hints are very welcome! I am totally stuck here and would love to solve it.

Thank you!

Comment: What's your mapping ?

Comment: You wanna get the total hits of the two aggregations ?

Comment: @Mathew Yes, that is basically it.

Comment: The `bucket_script` pipeline aggregation is meant to compute some metric for each bucket of the parent aggregation. In your case, your bucket_script aggregation named `hits_in_sum` is a sibling of the parent aggregation `allStreams` and is not a sub-aggregation of it, hence it's not possible to compute a per-bucket metric. It should be located inside `allStreams` not outside of it. Then I guess that the problem will be that you won't be able to reference the `downloads` aggregation within the `hits_in_sum` aggregation, but that's the main reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar query to yours using [Elastic Builder](https://elastic-builder.js.org/docs/)

- Github: https://github.com/sudo-suhas/elastic-builder
- Live editor: https://elastic-builder.js.org/

Can you try the generated JSON and see  if you still get the error message?

```
const medias_aggregation = esb.termsAggregation('medias', 'episode_id')
    .size(5)
    .minDocCount(1)
    .shardMinDocCount(0)
    .showTermDocCountError(false)
    .order('_count', 'desc')
    .order('_key', 'asc');

const downloads_filter = esb.filtersAggregation('downloads')
    .anonymousFilters([
        esb.boolQuery().must([
            esb.termQuery('status', '200'),
            esb.rangeQuery('bytes_sent')
                .from(2097152)
                .to(null)
                .includeLower(true)
                .includeUpper(true)
        ])
    ])
    .agg(medias_aggregation);

const streams_terms_aggregation = esb.termsAggregation('streams')
    .field('media')
    .size(65536)
    .minDocCount(1)
    .order('_count', 'desc')
    .order('_key', 'asc')
    .agg(
        esb.sumAggregation('transferred', 'bytes_sent'),
    )
    .agg(
        esb.bucketSelectorAggregation('threshold')
            .bucketsPath({total: 'transferred'})
            .script(
                esb.script('source', 'params.total > 2097152')
                    .lang('painless')
            )
    );

const streams_date_histogram = esb.dateHistogramAggregation('streams', 'time')
    .format('yyyy-MM-dd')
    .calendarInterval('day')
    .agg(streams_terms_aggregation)
    .agg(
        esb.statsBucketAggregation('valid_streams')
            .bucketsPath(['streams>transferred'])
    );

const all_streams_filter = esb.filterAggregation('allStreams')
    .filter(
        esb.boolQuery().must([
            esb.termQuery('status', '206')
                .boost(1.0)
        ])
    )
    .agg(streams_date_histogram);

const hits_in_sum_bucket_script = esb.bucketScriptAggregation('hits_in_sum')
    .bucketsPath({
        sum1: 'allStreams>streams>valid_streams.count',
        sum2: 'downloads'
    })
    .script(
        esb.script('source', 'params.sum1 + params.sum2')
            .lang('painless')
    )

const hits_filter = esb.filtersAggregation('hits__pod-b6a3b3e1ab4ddde42361e94107')
    .anonymousFilters([
        esb.boolQuery().must([
            esb.termsQuery('episode_id', 'pod-b6a3b3e1ab4ddde42361e94107')
        ])
    ])
    .agg(downloads_filter)
    .agg(all_streams_filter)
    .agg(hits_in_sum_bucket_script);

hits_filter.toJSON();
```

Comment: Thank you Yogev for your effort. Unfortunately I still get an error that I had before in one of my many tries: {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "",
    "phase" : "fetch",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "aggregation_execution_exception",
      "reason" : "buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [Object[]] at aggregation [allStreams]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}

Comment: @OpenHaus Based on https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/87880#issuecomment-1182661648 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68946528/4678126 try to change the path `allStreams>streams>valid_streams.count` (each link have different approach) as it seems that this is the reason for the error message

Comment: Sorry, I do not see how your linked answers are helping.